# Why was my flag declined with the statement "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"

Tags: support, answers, flags, declined-flags

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920216/5798798) while browsing around the site and, as you can see, it is low quality and should of been left as a comment.

I believe the question is low quality, as it tells the OP what to do, rather than showing them how to do it - something which would fit the comments section. They could of included an example of how to pass row values through Ajax.

[How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) says that a good answer provides examples, which this has not. In addition, I don't believe it is clear enough and has been rushed (without any detail being put into it). Now I understand that most answers don't include all of the points listed, but contain at least one or two - the answer I flagged contains **none**.

I flagged this question as low quality and this was the outcome from a moderator:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This note is very broad and ambiguous and does not apply to my flag - I was not indicating that the answer was wrong, or that there were any technical inaccuracies - my point was that the answer is low quality.

In fact, a comment has suggested that the answer (even though it is extremely broad) does provide the correct approach - I am still wondering where the idea of a "altogether wrong answer" came from:

> I too think it's a low quality as an answer and should be posted as comment instead. It has no code that "answers" the question, just a general **(and correct)** approach. I don't think answers like that are what make SO so great

May I ask why my flag was declined? Is the answer **not** low quality?

In addition, this brings me to my next point that the answer has been upvoted twice. An answer given in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/325872 says that a question should be upvoted if:

- The answer is clear
- The answer explains the concept (e.g why they should do this).

The mentioned answer includes none of the points mentioned, and has the **same amount** of upvotes as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920251/5798798) which provides an extreme amount of detail, including resources and a clear explanation.

Is this right?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasons that you think the answer is _very low quality_?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yep, I've added that.

Comment: I too think it's a low quality as an answer and should be posted as comment instead. It has no code that "answers" the question, just a general (and correct) approach. I don't think answers like that are what make SO so great

Comment: @AlonEitan And the fact that it has received the same amount of upvotes as a brilliant answer (which goes into detail, explains why and has links to resources) on the same question is shocking.

Comment: @TheCodesee I think you're responsible for one of the upvotes :)  Looking at their [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6171211/shi?tab=reputation&sort=time), they had an upvote 10 minutes after you posted your question here, and I guess that the other upvote is from the OP

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm responsible for them loosing an upvote :)

Comment: @AlonEitan Hehe, well I give up. Flagged it as 'not an answer' (as it clearly should of been a comment) and it was declined.

Comment: @TheCodesee Yeah, it's for the best. Some anomalies will occur from time to time

Comment: @TheCodesee: I understand what you feel... Two of my flags have been declined today, even though the answers (comments?) are incredibly low quality: [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44215681/6910253) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44216816/6910253). I thought Stack Overflow had high standards, so why the hell would we keep terrible content?

Answer (score 6):

That answer *is* an attempt to answer the question, however wrong it may be, and it is not unarguable garbage that should be deleted immediately.

The reason your flag was declined is:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

There is a very big difference between "low quality" and "very low quality". The "very low quality" flag should be used for content that no reasonable person would ever consider to be anything other than absolute unarguable garbage that should be deleted as soon as humanly possible.

[Two users also agreed that the post should not have been flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15036359) before it was pushed into a moderator queue, where it was declined by a moderator because the post does not qualify for the criteria set forth for the flag.

Comment: Based on how the community reviews were going, it would have been declined anyway if a moderator had not done so: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15036359 . It lingered long enough in review to pass to the moderator review queue, so the last action on it was taken by a moderator.

Comment: This note is very broad and ambiguous and does not apply to my flag - I was not indicating that the answer was wrong, or that there were any technical inaccuracies - my point was that the answer is low quality. From your response, I am assuming that you agree that the answer was low quality, but I do respect that it is an attempt to answer the question. Would marking my flag as 'helpful' of been a better choice?

Comment: @The I clarified that a bit in an edit

Comment: Where did the impression that I was implying a "technical inaccuracies" or "altogether wrong answer" come from? I have also updated my question with reference to the upvotes the answer has received.

Comment: @The Why would you flag a technically accurate and correct answer as unarguable garbage that must be deleted immediately?

Comment: @TinyGiant That isn't the point and diverts from my original question. Maybe my flag should of been marked as "not an answer" but I totally disagree with the "declined" status and the note with it which is totally wrong and I feel was rubber stamped without being properly looked into.

Comment: The flag was declined because the post does not fit within *any* current flag criteria. There is a very big difference between "low quality" and "very low quality". The "very low quality" flag should be used for content that no reasonable person would ever consider to be anything other than absolute unarguable garbage that should be deleted as soon as humanly possible. Downvotes and delete votes are for low quality content.

Comment: Well then I guess the answer is neither low quality or very low quality as it's received two upvotes, the same amount as the accepted answer (which in my opinion is a **brilliant** example of an SO answer as it explains why, it is detailed and even includes links to references)  - is that logical? Also, why someone, somehow inferred that I was implying the answer was "wrong all together" is still out of my reach.

Comment: *"Well then I guess the answer is neither low quality or very low quality as it's received two upvotes"* Oh my, two people used their votes as they saw fit. How dare they!

Comment: *"Also, why someone, somehow inferred that I was implying the answer was "wrong all together" is still out of my reach"* I cannot fathom flagging a technically accurate and correct answer as unarguable garbage that must be deleted immediately.

Comment: @TinyGiant Ah, that is assumption and also diverts from my question, **again**. I believe (from your response) that you agree with me that the answer is correct - so again, why someone, somehow inferred that I was implying the answer was "wrong all together" is still out of my reach.

Comment: I honestly don't care enough about the specific question and answer to determine whether the answer is correct or not, and that is not required to determine whether the post should be flagged or not. If a post appears to be an attempt to answer the question and is not absolute unarguable garbage that any reasonable person would agree should be deleted immediately, it should not be flagged. At that point, the reviewer of the flag is left to assume that you were using the flag to say the answer is wrong, which is why your flag was declined with that message.